# background-image doesn't work(wrong path?)

Tags: css, sass, path, background-image

my CSS file is placed: task1/scss/input.scss

and my image is placed: task1/png/header_background.png

I tried **background-image: url("../png/header_background.png");** but it doesn't work.

any support appreciated

Comment: Where is your final CSS being compiled? Does the path still make sense?

Comment: task1/css/ouput.css

Comment: If you can supply a link to the live code, this would be much easier to solve.

Comment: solved already. placed tags with content and background-image started working

Answer (score 1):

Your .scss it's a preprocessor, so you need to find where's your actual (generated) css file located and try to figure out why image not working from there.

Also, why not to open Dev. tools in your browser and check the console logs to find some errors about wrong path?

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your folder structure, your CSS file should be at `task1/css/input.scss`

For short, use `background-image:  url("../../png/header_background.png")`.

The first `../` will navigate up to `task1/css`, and the second `../` will navigate to your `task1` folder.